# Using Aggregate Functions in a single sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm curious if it is possible to do the following

select id
from foo
where foo.bar =
    (select SUM(bar)
    from foo
    )

without the use of a subquery.

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to do this with postgresql, which does not appear to support the two solutions posted thus far.

Comment: `select SUM(bar) from foo` will return a single value for the entire table foo. Is this what you are trying to achieve, or is your actual requirement more complicated, and if it is more complicated, can you give us more details?

Answer (score 2):

You can try a similar thing using joins, although it is less clear than the subquery

```
SELECT f1.id
FROM foo f1
CROSS JOIN foo f2
WHERE f1.bar = SUM(f2.bar)
GROUP BY f1.id, f1.bar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Its not possible to write it without sub query
see the Below Link for more Help
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/tutorial-agg.html
```